# Why am I getting these errors in my Server/Client Chatroom program?

Tags: java

I've been working on this program for a few hours now, so I'm pretty brain-dead and cannot figure out why I'm getting these errors. Being fairly new to Java programming doesn't help my case much either.

```
On line 27 - "error: method Add in class ClientManager cannot be applied to given types;"
On line 34 - "error: cannot find symbol"
Also line 34 - "error: cannot find symbol"
On line 42 - "error: cannot find symbol"
```

Now here are segments of my code for those particular lines:

```
Line 27 - CM.Add();
Line 34 - MyClient Client = new MyClient(Socket, CM);
Line 42 - Client.SendToAllClients(S);
```

Here's my full code for the Server class. The client class works perfectly.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new MyServer().start();
    }   
}

class MyServer extends Thread
{
    ServerSocket SS = new ServerSocket(11200);
    Socket S;
    ClientManager CM = new ClientManager();

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            S = SS.accept();
            CM.Add();
        }
    }
}

class MyClient extends Thread
{
    MyClient Client = new MyClient(Socket, CM);
    Scanner S;

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            S = new Scanner(System.in);
            Client.SendToAllClients(S);
        }
    }

    public void Send(String S)
    {
        PrintWriter.println(S);
    }       
}

class ClientManager
{
    MyClient[] X = new MyClient[15];
    int num = 0;

    public synchronized void Add(MyClient C)
    {
        X[num] = C;
        num++;
        C.start();
    }

    public synchronized void SendToAllClient(String S)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0;i < num;i++);
        {
            X[i].Send(S);
        }
    }   
}
```

Update: I'm not sure what parameter needs to go in `CM.Add();`

Comment: 27)`CM.add()` needs a parameter. 34)`MyClient Client = new MyClient(Socket, CM);` Initialization should be in a constructor or method. `Client.SendToAllClients(S);` 42) MyClient (which is of the type `Client`) doesn't have a method `SendToAllClients`, that method is in `ClientManager`. 48) You failed to create an object of `PrintWriter`.

Comment: So far, the only problem I've been able to fix is the PrintWriter object. I'm not sure what parameter to put in CM.Add() and the others, I've just no idea..

Comment: I see `public synchronized void Add(MyClient C)` in the `ClientManager` class. When you use that method in `MyServer` you must pass it a `MyClient` object.

Comment: As you are a new user here, I would like to tell you if any answer solves your problem then you should accept the answer, so others could know what worked for you. To accept an answer you just need to click on the right tick sign on the left side of the answer below the up down arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you the reason why you are getting these errors. You need to understand it and then make changes according to what you need.

`Line 27 - CM.Add();`

In your `ClientManager` class, the signature of method is `public synchronized void Add(MyClient C)` So you can see, it needs one parameter i.e. object of class MyClient but when you are calling this method then you are not passing any parameter.

`MyClient Client = new MyClient(Socket, CM);`

In this line you are trying to create object of class `MyClient` and passing two arguments Socket and CM objects but in your class MyClient you have not created any such constructor which will accept two parameters, by default there will be only **default** constructor, which can be called something like `new MyClient();` if you want to pass parameters then you need to create a parameterized constructor your self.

`Client.SendToAllClients(S);`

Here `Client` is object of class `MyClient` and the method `SendToAllClients(s)` is present in `ClientManager` class, you if you want to call this method then you need an object of `ClientManager` class, you cannot call it with the object of `MyClient`.

---

Apart from it I would like to tell you, you are not following naming conventions of Java. It is a good practice to follow naming conventions, it helps others to understand your code easily. [Check this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Thank for you the help, but I was wondering if you could give me more specific information.. I'm very new to Java and probably 70% of this code was provided by my professor. I was pretty much told to fill in the blanks. I added the parameter C to the CM.Add(); but I am not familiar enough with constructors to know exactly what to do for my second problem. Thank you for your time!